# Como no remplazar mi ultimo mensaje de commit tras hacer un pull

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull

Resulta que tengo acceso a un repositorio en GitLab donde debo subir ejercicios de programación.

Esos retos pueden ser varios archivos e incluso puedo modificar algunos archivos que ya otra persona había subido al repositorio, así logró completar mi commit y enviarlo a mi rama remota para hacer el merge request y que sea integrado al master, en este proceso ese commit pasa por pipelines para verificar que cumpla con algunos criterios, el caso es que algunas veces no pasa esos pipelines ya sea por error en mi código u otro caso, ok entonces se me pide que lo corrija y yo lo hago los cambios y uso el comando git commit --amend --no-edit para no cambiar el mensaje de commit. Hasta alli todo bien, el inconveniente que tengo es el siguiente cuando se hacen cambios en master debo integrarlos a mi rama pero tengo entendido que cada vez que hago el pull request para traer los cambios remotos a mi local siempre se me crea un nuevo commit ya que esto hace un merge y entonces ese nuevo commit que se creó queda en mi HEAD y yo no necesito eso ya que mi head debe apuntar al commit del reto que estoy resolviendo para que cualquier modificación que yo haga la pueda enviar nuevamente y sea revisada entonces cuando hago el push se me envia es el commit que se creó debido a los cambios que traje del remoto.
A continuación una imagen donde se muestra  que mi rama siempre debe apuntar a ese último commit que dice chall\sol\code…
Esto siempre debe ser así no importa que yo haga pull para traer cambios en el master.

No entiendo muy bien que deberia hacer ya que de momento lo que estoy haciendo es clonar el repositorio siempre que esto sucede.

agradezco mucho cualquier docuemtación o sugerencia al respecto.

Comment: No entiendo bien. Al hacer `git commit --amend --no-edit` estás creando un **nuevo commit**, no estás parado sobre el commit original.... así que no veo cual podría ser el inconveniente de traerte los cambios de la rama master _original_, cosa que haría con un `git rebase` o con un `git pull -r` para asegurarme de no meter merges sino quedar con un solo commit con todos los cambios que estoy introduciendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes algo de confusión acerca de como traer los cambios de una rama upstream.

Asumiendo que en tu local tienes vista de la rama `main` upstream, y que el remoto donde está alojada se llama `origin`. Digamos que las ramas se ven así:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- (origin/main)
     ^
      \- F <- (mi-rama)
```

Parado en tu rama, puedes hacer esto.

```
git pull -r origin main
```

Con eso no vas a hacer un merge sino hacer un rebase de tu rama sobre la rama `origin/main`. Si tu rama tenía un solo commit separado de `origin/main`, al terminar el rebase, vas a quedar de nuevo con un solo commit *sobre* `origin/main`.

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- (origin/main)
                    ^
                     \- F' <- (mi-rama)
```

Nota, el commit ahora es `F'` porque no es el `F` original, pero es un cambio *equivalente* (desde el punto de vista delas modificaciones *textuales* a los archivos del proyecto, digamos).

Una forma sencilla de lograr lo mismo (y es lo que yo hago, aunque implica 2 pasos en vez de uno solo) es:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/main
```

También hay workflows que actualizan la rama `main` **local** para hacer luego el rebase, pero yo no lo hago de esa forma.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon. gracias por la respuesta.